# Android Versions Not Displaying SimpleDateFormat as Expected

Tags: java, android, date

```
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Date date = new Date(millisUntilFinished);
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("m:ss.S");

            timeRemaining.setText(formater.format(date));
        }
```

This is the code in my onTick method for a CountDownTimer.  My question is that on 2 different android devices (4.4.4) & (5.0) the text is showing up differently.

On 4.4.4 it shows up as m:ss.SSS

On 5.0 it shows as expected m:ss.S

This is reproduced in any method of showing text (debug, Toast, TextView) so it is not a display or font issue, it is with the SimpleDateFormat

First Image INCORRECT (Android 4.4.4)

[image: INCORRECT (Android 4.4.4)]

Second Image CORRECT (Android 5.0)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is actually normal. Have a look at the SimpleDateFormat documentation.

S   fractional seconds  (Number)    978

There is no "SSS", fractional seconds (aka "S") can be any value (most likely between 0 and 1000).

EDIT: you can eventually fix is this way too:

```
                Date date = new Date();
                String myTimerString = new SimpleDateFormat("m:ss.", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
                String myTimerFraction = new SimpleDateFormat("S", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
                if (myTimerFraction.length()>1)
                    myTimerFraction = myTimerFraction.substring(0,1);
                myTimerString += myTimerFraction;
```

Comment: both "m:ss:S" and "m:ss:SS" and even "m:ss:SSSS" format as expected in Android 5.0

Comment: Then it's a new feature in 5.0, or a bug fix maybe. My javadoc for SimpleDateFormat clearly says that just "S" can display 3 digits though. I tested on my Xperia Z Ultra which also runs Kitkat (4.4.4) and it does the same than on your Samsung under 4.4.4.

Comment: i found a work around, not real clean...
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2118022

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is related with the `text size` on different devices with different `dpi`.You have to create different `<dimen>` sizes for different devices.

> The time is probably formatted correctly but it is not shown at all
>    devices with different dpi (i mean that the last two characters are not shown but they exist there)

so instead of:

`android:textSize="36sp"`

use something like:

`android:textSize="@dimens/text_size" />`

where `dimens` folder is included in different `values folders` with different `text size` (ex: in `values>dimens.xml` and `values-xxhdpi>dimens.xml`)

***note:*** Also be sure that you didnt play with `Settings>Font size`. IF you want to avoid that also then you have to get rid of `sp` and instead use `dp`

Comment: Its actually two of the same device, Galaxy S5, one running 4.4.4 and the other running 5.0.  See updated xml

Comment: this might be true. try to view the value from somewhere else, _toast_ for example

Comment: have you checked `settings > font size` if they are same on both devices? Maybe someone played with those settings

Comment: @KailuaBum change `android:textSize="36sp" />` to `android:textSize="36dp" />` and try if it works

Comment: toast also shows format differently, m:ss.S vs. m:ss:SSS.  this tells me that its not a font size issue

Comment: try changing `SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("m:ss.S");` to `SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("m:ss.SSS");` and again `show on toast` or log it to `logcat` and tell what it is showing on both devices

Comment: @hrskrs it shows as m:ss.SSS on both devices, in textView and Toast

Comment: Ok now change `sp` of `textSize` to `dp` and check if it is showing correctly on both devices

Comment: sp & dp will have no effect on Toast.  So it has to be an issue with the formatting not the displaying of the TextView

Comment: @KailuaBum i said change that and try on your devices where do you want textiew to appear if they are showing correctly, not on your toast. If this will show correctly then read my edited answer and use those strategies

Comment: @hrskrs it is not showing correctly on Android 4.4.4, it is showing as m:ss.SSS regardless of how I set the SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @KailuaBum can you please provide some screenshots? Also have you checked `settings->font size` if same for both devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72392/discussion-between-kailua-bum-and-hrskrs).